# Obtaining First and Last Charsof Each String From A Vector of Strings

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have created a `vector<string> names;` which stores peoples first names. I want to take each name and create two variables `first_letter` and `last_letter` which contains the first and last characters of each name. However I am not quite sure how to get this done since I am just starting with c++. Can anyone explain to me how this can be done, and possibly provide an example?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `name` is your `string` and you're OK with using C++11, [`name.front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) and [`name.back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) will work, otherwise dereference the iterator: [`*name.begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) and [`*name.rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin). Though you'd check whether the `name` is empty or not:

```
if (!name.empty()) {
    // Safe to proceed now
}
```

You can iterate over `names` like ([range loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) - since C++11)

```
for (auto& name : names) {
    // Do things with individual name
}
```

or (for older C++)

```
for (vector<string>::iterator it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); it++) {
    // Do things with individual name (*it)
}
```

It's advised to use constant iterators where possible, if you're not planning to modify strings, replace `auto` with `const auto` and `::iterator` with `::const_iterator`.

Comment: *name.begin() and *name.rbegin() work with a string but I can't get it to work with my `vector<string> names;`.

Comment: Also: most of the time, I'd write the second loop: `for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator current = names.begin(), end = names.end(); current != end; ++ current )...` (accessing `*current` in the loop, of course).  In other words, putting the definition of the iterator in the `for` statement, and using a `const_iterator` if I wasn't modifying anything in the array.  (Similarly, for the first version, I'd use `for ( std::string const& name : names )`, with a const reference, and avoiding the obfuscation of the `auto`.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 it got easier:

```
for (std::string& name : names) {
     char first_letter = name.front();
     char last_letter = name.back();
     // do stuff
}
```

Before that, you'd have to access them directly using `operator[]`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i) {
     std::string& name = names[i];

     char first_letter = name[0];
     char last_letter = name[name.size() - 1];
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: you can access vector string characters by using `[]` ?

Comment: @NinjaZ I'm assuming `name` is a `string`, as in `for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i) { string& name = names[i]; char first = name.front(); }`

Comment: I am using a vector of strings though.

Comment: @NinjaZ I added the loops into my answer, does that help clarify things?

Answer (score 2):

Use the string functions `front()` and `back()`.

**Make sure that the string is not empty before using these functions:**

Assuming that `i` is an index into your vector:

```
if ( !names[i].empty() )
{
    char fChar = names[i].front();
    char bChar = names[i].back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to get the two letters from a single string:

```
std::pair<char, char>
first_and_last(const std::string& s)
{
  if (s.length() == 0)
    throw std::runtime_error("Empty string!")
  return {s.front(), s.back()};
}
```

(for C++03 `return std::make_pair(s[0], s[s.length()-1])` or another of the ways to do it shown by the other answers.)

Then apply that function to each name in turn, saving the results in a new vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<char, char>> letters;
letters.reserve(names.size());
std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), std::back_inserter(letters), first_and_last);
```

Or use the C++11 range-based `for` loop:

```
std::vector<std::pair<char, char>> letters;
letters.reserve(names.size());
for (const auto& name : names)
  letters.push_back( first_and_last(name) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? There's no error checking, but it's a start.

```
vector<string> names = ...;
for (vector<string>::iterator i = names.begin(); i != names.end(); ++i)
{
    string first_letter = i->substr(0, 1);
    string last_letter = i->substr(i->size() - 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why create a string when you're dealing with a single character?

Comment: There's really not enough context to worry about whether we use the `string` created by `substr` or just the first `char` extracted from it. It's just a starting point for the questioner.

Comment: _"There's really not enough context "_ - Yes there is. From the posted question - _"create two variables first_letter and last_letter which contains the first and last **characters**"_.

Comment: Well I did give him 2 variables that contain the first and last characters, they just happen to contain other information too :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, of course, you start with a loop to iterate through the vector.
Then you get those characters with substr, it would look something like this

```
vector <string>::iterator it;
for(it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); it++)
{
    string first = (*it).substr(0, 1);
    string second = (*it).substr((*it).length()-1, 1);
    ..
    do whatever you want to
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v { "Hello", "NinjaZ", "How", "do", "you", "do" };

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::pair<char, char>> v2;
    v2.reserve( v.size() );

    std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                    std::back_inserter( v2 ),
                    []( const std::string &s )
                    {
                        return std::make_pair( s.front(), s.back() );
                    } );

    for ( const auto &p : v2 )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hello NinjaZ How do you do 
H o
N Z
H w
d o
y u
d o
```

Instead of the algorithm `std::transform` you could use an ordinary range based for loop. For example

```
for ( const auto &s : v ) v2.push_back( { s.front(), s.back() } );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat.

Here's another short readable example using C++11. What this brings to the table is the use of `std::vector::emplace_back` which allows for in-place construction of elements, as opposed to move- or copyconstructing. Also shorter syntax which is nice.

Say you have a container that stores the pairs of letters.

```
std::vector<std::pair<char, char>> letters;
```

Then use this:

```
for (auto&& name : names)
    letters.emplace_back(name.front(), name.back());
```

If you want to throw on empty name strings, simply add a statement before the `std::vector::emplace_back` statement:

```
if (name.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty string!");
```